# Gridstack.js save data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am starting to play with GridStack to try and replace a page I made with Gridster. The ability to work well with bootstrap and to be responsive is appealing.

There seems to be a major lack of documentation and I am struggling with just saving the data.

Here is the page I have so far - http://ededit.com/testing/test.html

I found this page on stack overflow and the cod works when I move or resize an object, but I cannot figure out to just access the data by clicking a button

[How can I parse gridstack.js items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668926/how-can-i-parse-gridstack-js-items)

My end goal is to click a "Save" button and have it output json (id, width, height, x, y)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I found an "issue" on github and figured it out from there. Calling the function below will output the data in json format.

```
function saveData() {
    var items = [];

    $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        items.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
        });
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated README file with a sample https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#save-grid-to-array